# How to add ckeditor simple upload adapter/fix CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor

I'm trying to add CKEditor in Vue and it works fine. Now I'd like to add the ability to add images in the text area and I've tried the simple upload adapter as shown below but it's not working. The page with the editor doesn't show and the following error is thrown in the console `CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules`. How can I fix this or I'm I implementing it wrongly?

```
<template>
  <ckeditor
    :editor="editor"
    v-model="editorData"
    @ready="onReady"
    @input="onChange"
    :config="editorConfig"
  ></ckeditor>
</template>

<script>
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue";
import SimpleUploadAdapter from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    ckeditor: CKEditor.component,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorData: "<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>",

      editorConfig: {
        plugins: [SimpleUploadAdapter],
        toolbar: ["imageUpload", "image"],
        simpleUpload: {
          uploadUrl: "YOUR_UPLOAD_ENDPOINT_URL",
        },
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onReady(editor) {
      console.log("CKEditor5 Vue Component is ready to use!", editor);
    },
    onChange(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like:

```
<template>
  <ckeditor
    :editor="editor"
    v-model="editorData"
    @ready="onReady"
    @input="onChange"
    :config="editorConfig"
  ></ckeditor>
</template>

<script>
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import SimpleUploadAdapter from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter";

export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorData: "<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>",

      editorConfig: {
        plugins: [SimpleUploadAdapter],
        toolbar: ["imageUpload", "image"],
        simpleUpload: {
          uploadUrl: "YOUR_UPLOAD_ENDPOINT_URL",
        },
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onReady(editor) {
      console.log("CKEditor5 Vue Component is ready to use!", editor);
    },
    onChange(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```